# Deploying NodeJS and MySQL REST API on a live environment

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, rest

I'm developing a full stack application with React (Front-End) + Google maps API and Node + Express + MySQL for REST API end points. Was able to connect and successfully hit all the end points for CRUD operations in local(with help of Workbench) and 60% of functionality done. Now want to deploy the work so far to a live server and incrementally push changes and deploy to live server. But pain point is choosing the platform.

Though I have experience deploying single page react apps to Heroku and Netlify, and Backends to Hostinger, this time it's node and MySQL. Having hard times with Heroku due to SQL data export to JAWSDB and ClearDB (too many access issues and not so user friendly GUI for DB management). Google Cloud - trial version expired, not sure of premium at development phase. AWS - not really sure (so much of terminology to research).

Can someone please guide me in this scenario. Though I can start learning AWS and try that, looking for some easier alternatives, as I want to focus on project, rather than platform.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the digital ocean platform they also provide a 100$ 3 months trial And deploying nodejs code is very easy.

Steps-
1)Signup to Digital Ocean
2)Use nodejs Droplet(Instance)
3)upload your code in that instance
4)Done

Answer (score 0):

You can provision everything you need within AWS free tier:

- AWS RDS for MySQL database
- AWS Lambda function for hosting your NodeJS code
- AWS HTTP API for exposing your Lambda as HTTP
- AWS S3 for uploading your react build